# Should I rank my data before doing post hoc Dunn test?

Tags: python, multiple-comparisons, friedman-test, dunn-test

I am trying to compare multiple algorithms using the Friedman test and post hoc Dunn test. I know that we should use the rank of our data before performing the Friedman test, but should we rank the data for Dunn test too? I am using python to perform the tests. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import scikit_posthocs as sp
print("Q synthetic statistical test:")

q_synthetic = {
"DATA_1": [0.61,0.54,0.59,0.52,0.59,0.54,0.62,0.52,0.49,0.50,0.47,0.62,0.60,0.56],
"DATA_2": [0.43,0.43,0.24,0.24,0.43,0.43,0.43,0.24,0.43,0.43,0.43,0.43,0.43,0.43],
"DATA_3": [0.82,0.82,0.64,0.61,0.82,0.74,0.82,0.74,0.82,0.82,0.82,0.81,0.82,0.82],
"DATA_4": [0.70,0.58,0.10,0.20,0.70,0.58,0.70,0.70,0.70,0.70,0.70,0.69,0.70,0.70],
"DATA_5": [0.53,0.11,0.10,0.10,0.53,0.10,0.53,0.53,0.53,0.53,0.53,0.53,0.53,0.53],
"DATA_6": [0.66,0.11,0.10,0.10,0.66,0.18,0.66,0.66,0.66,0.66,0.66,0.66,0.66,0.66]
}

dataframe_q_synthetic = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(q_synthetic, orient='index',
                                   columns=["ALGO_1", "ALGO_2", "ALGO_3", "ALGO_4", "ALGO_5", "ALGO_6", "ALGO_7","ALGO_8", "ALGO_9", "ALGO_10", "ALGO_11", "ALGO_12", "ALGO_13", "ALGO_14"])
general_dataframe_q_synthetic = dataframe_q_synthetic
l_data = pd.melt(general_dataframe_q_synthetic, var_name='criteria', value_name='score')
p_values_general_q_synthetic = sp.posthoc_dunn(l_data, val_col='score', group_col='criteria', p_adjust='bonferroni')    
res = friedmanchisquare(general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_1"],general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_2"],general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_3"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_4"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_5"] ,general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_6"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_7"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_8"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_9"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_10"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_11"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_12"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_13"], general_dataframe_q_synthetic["ALGO_14"])
print("friedman test: ")
print(res)
print("algorithms p_values")
print(p_values_general_q_synthetic)
```

It returns all 1.0 matrix which means there is no significant difference between any of the groups while the Friedman test shows the existence of a significant difference. Therefore, I suppose there should be some mistake. Now, should I change my input to ranks? For example, should I write my data like this:

```
q_synthetic = {
    "DATA_1": [12, 6, 9, 4, 9, 6, 13, 4, 2, 3, 1, 13, 11, 8], ...
```

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

Dunn's test is applied to ranks of the original data, and when implemented properly, corrects for ties. The specific ranks used are those applied to all data taken across all groups (i.e. Dunn's test uses the same ranks as the Kruskal-Wallis test), and **not** merely ranks within the two groups being compared in a single *post hoc* test.

Aside: Friedman's test is for **repeated measures** (blocked) data, while Dunn's test is for unblocked data.

Dunn, O. J. (1964). Multiple Comparisons Using Rank Sums. *Technometrics*, 6(3), 241–252.